# Json to html ul list. Pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

How to convert json response into html `ul` list?

```
{
    "subject": [
        "The subject field is required."
    ],
    "message": [
        "The message field is required."
    ]
}
```

to this

```
<ul>
    <li>The subject field is required</li>
    <li>The message field is required</li>
</ul>
```

And show it in some div

```
<div id="errors"></div>
```

Comment: have you already tried something? what failed?

Comment: I guess you'd start with a JavaScript tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var parent = document.createElement("ul");
document.body.appendChild(parent);

var obj = {
    "subject": [
        "The subject field is required."
    ],
    "message": [
        "The message field is required."
    ]
}

var keys = Object.keys(obj);

for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  var child = document.createElement("li");
  child.innerHTML = obj[keys[i]][0];
  parent.appendChild(child);
}
```

Comment: Still I suggest you to try out things of your own. And rather than blindly following my answer, just use it as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways but the most intuitive for me it to build HTML as a string then use element.innerHTML property to inject the html string inside the div element

To build the HTML do something like this

```
var theHTMLString = "<ul>";
for(var propertyName in myObject) {
   theHTMLString += "<li>" + myObject[propertyName] + "</li>";
}
theHTMLString += "</ul>";
```

NOTE: If the JSON response might contain HTML such as:

```
</li>
```

then the above will create malformed HTML so you might want to explore HTML encoding:

http://jsfiddle.net/thinkingstiff/fsau2/

Or you might want to do it another way using the .createElement() function and innerText instead of innerHTML to avoid encoding issues.

once you've done this you need to access the div as a JS object so you can do stuff with it. The easiest way is:

```
var theDiv = document.getElementById( "errors" );
```

Now we've for the object and the HTML we want to inject into it just use add the HTML to the div...

```
theDIV.innerHTML = theHTMLString;
```